# iOS 11 UISearchBar: left + rightbarbuttonitem vertical center issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, ios11, rightbarbuttonitem

With IOS 11, I've encountered another one issue in `UISearchController`.
As default height value became 56 `rightBarButtonItem` and `leftBarButtonItem` are staying in their old places, regardless of whether it's text or image.

I need to centre items to the search bar as it were in IOS 10.

[refresh buttons are not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSHkb.png)

As you can see the item buttons are bit higher than center of searchbar.

I tried to do: `[self.searchController.searchBar.heightAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant: 44].active = YES;`

But I got search bar overlapping buttons:

[searchbar overlaps buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO8X1.png)

However, after I enter edit mode and return back by pressing Cancel - it begins to look good in case of 44 constraints.

I also tried to play with setting `centerYanchor` to `imageView` (of button) same as in `searchBar` but had crashed.

Comment: [self.searchController.searchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = YES; - is buggy on start and good alignment after in-out from editing mode. Still have no idea.

Comment: GIF: https://gyazo.com/1091697cd2759e4507740fef7eb0323a

Comment: I noticed from your video that the UISearchBar is shifting some pixel down when becomes first risponder. I have the same problem, I tried @canadaboy code but no success. Did that fix the shifting down for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [self.searchBar.heightAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant: 44].active = YES;
    }
}
```